# How can I pass a firebase token to a Laravel app?

Tags: laravel, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've made an app with Laravel.  I need to create Android/iOS app also, and I am using Flutter with WebView.

I have to integrate push notifications with Firebase, so that it works on Android/iOS and in Laravel also. But I don't know how I can pass a user token, and device type, to my Laravel app and a link token to the logged in user.

**In the Laravel app**:

I have created a controller with a `store()` (method) token in **User Model** and `sendMessage()` (method) using curl (action POST) to send a notification to a device/user.

**In Flutter framework:**

I have integrated Firebase Messaging plugin and installed it.  This works fine if I send the notification from Console.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass token from header, and to get token in your controllers method use `$token = $request->header('token');`